# how to change the size of input image to a tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow's super resolution model but  the size of the input  to the model is hardcoded to 50 x 50. I want the model to be able to accept input image of any size but when I change this hardcoded input size of 50 x 50 to any other value say 1026 x 720 it generates an error!

```
!pip install matplotlib tensorflow tensorflow-hub
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(tf.__version__)
model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/captain-pool/esrgan-tf2/1")
concrete_func = model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
concrete_func.inputs[0].set_shape([1, 1026, 720, 3])
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the TF Lite model.
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('ESRGAN.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

esrgan_model_path = './ESRGAN.tflite'
test_img_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('lr.jpg', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/examples/master/lite/examples/super_resolution/android/app/src/main/assets/lr-1.jpg')
lr = tf.io.read_file(test_img_path)
lr = tf.image.decode_jpeg(lr)
lr = tf.expand_dims(lr, axis=0)
lr = tf.cast(lr, tf.float32)

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=esrgan_model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Run the model
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], lr)
interpreter.invoke()

# Extract the output and postprocess it
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
sr = tf.squeeze(output_data, axis=0)
sr = tf.clip_by_value(sr, 0, 255)
sr = tf.round(sr)
sr = tf.cast(sr, tf.uint8)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-4f3adfe8870a> in <module>()
     13 
     14 # Run the model
---> 15 interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], lr)
     16 interpreter.invoke()
     17 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py in set_tensor(self, tensor_index, value)
    421       ValueError: If the interpreter could not set the tensor.
    422     """``
--> 423     self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
    424 
    425   def resize_tensor_input(self, input_index, tensor_size, strict=False):

ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 50 but expected 1026 for dimension 1 of input 0.
```

Comment: You can only input data to a neural network as the same shape it has been trained on. For your use case, if you want to accept variable image sizes you can write a preprocessing function which accepts images of variable size and resizes them to the input shape (50 x 50), then feed that image to the network.

Comment: please desertnaut how can i do this? I am an android developer and a newbie to machine learning

Comment: You can change your image shape using `lr = tf.image.resize(image, (50, 50))`. Add this line after `lr = tf.image.decode_jpeg(lr)`. Refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it). And change your `concrete_func.inputs[0].set_shape([1, 1026, 720, 3])` model inputs to its orignal shape.

Comment: It gives an error on this line lr = tf.image.resize(image, (50, 50)) saying "images must have 3 or 4 dimensions"

Comment: Then specify `lr = tf.image.resize(image, (50, 50, 3))` or `lr = tf.image.resize(image, (1, 50, 50, 3))`

Comment: Thanks kishore I was able to resize the image but it degraded the picture the more. Is there not a way I can retrain this model and use a dataset of much bigger pixel like 1080 x 620 or something else bigger than 50 x 50 image size?

Comment: Is the super resolution output image also looks bad ? Also we can fine tune a model for our specific purposes if we want but we cannot change it's input shape as the architecture of the model depends on it.

Comment: Yes it looks bad after I scaled down the image size to 50 x 50 and applied the super resolution on it